# Mails from Google accounts can't be forwarded with mail rules

Tags: catalina, mail.app

I have a very simple Mail mail rule: If mail arrives to a certain account that mail should be moved to a mailbox and then redirected to another mail address.

It works perfectly with all domains, except for mails coming from google.com where the forwarding does not work.

macOS Catalina 10.15.7 on a Mac mini 2018.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this? Any solution?

Comment: Does it silently fail, does the mail get sent but is never received, do you get an error message?

Comment: There is no error message, the mail is simply not forwarded.